# How to fix the variable "t" error in python?

Tags: python

I have this code and I get an error when I tried to convert to farenheit. It's basically a windchill calculator:

```
    import math
c = ""
f = ""
t = 0


def temp (t):
   t = (9/5 * temp_chosen) + 32
temp_chosen = float(input("What is the temperature? :"))
scale = input("Farenheit or Celsius (F/C)? ").upper()   

def wind():
   if scale == "C":
      return (t)
      print(t)

   else:
      t = temp_chosen
      print(t)

      for i in range (5, 65, 5):
         wind_chill = 35.74 + (0.6215 * t) -35.75 * (i ** 0.16) + 0.4275 * ((t)) * (i ** 0.16)
         print(f"At temperature {t}F, and wind speed {i} mph, the windchill is: {wind_chill:.2f}F")


temp (t)  
wind ()
```

And I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:/Users/Azevedo/Documents/Codes/test.py", line 28, in <module>
    wind ()
  File "c:/Users/Azevedo/Documents/Codes/test.py", line 14, in wind
    return (t)
UnboundLocalError: local variable 't' referenced before assignment
```

How can I fix that?

Comment: Please fix the indentation of your code. It's impossible to know what you meant to write.

Comment: Even aside from the indentation, I'm sorry to say, but most of this code shows a fundamental lack of understanding in how variables and functions work. I recommend a good beginner Python tutorial. Take it slow and learn one concept at a time. Throwing together a bunch of code you don't understand accomplishes nothing.

Comment: basic indentation errors in your code. As @SilvioMayolo said take a good beginner python tutorial and take one step at a time to understand it.

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to return a value that is not defined. Well it is defined but you need to pass it in to wind. Try this piece of code, fixed a couple bugs you had.

```
import math
c = ""
f = ""
t = 0


def temp (t):
   t = (9/5 * temp_chosen) + 32
   return t
temp_chosen = float(input("What is the temperature? :"))
scale = input("Farenheit or Celsius (F/C)? ").upper()   
def wind(t):
   if scale == "C":
      return (t)

   else:
      t = temp_chosen
      print(t)

      for i in range (5, 65, 5):
         wind_chill = 35.74 + (0.6215 * t) -35.75 * (i ** 0.16) + 0.4275 * ((t)) * (i ** 0.16)
         print(f"At temperature {t}F, and wind speed {i} mph, the windchill is: {wind_chill:.2f}F")


t = temp (t)  
wind (t)
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to add `global t` at the top of your function. Because, Python works in scopes : In your case one module or script scope that holds all variables, functions, etc. that are directly in the script (e.g. not indented at all).`t` is in this one. And a function scope for each function, each holding the variables of the function. In that one you try to reference `t`. Scopes are not nested, instead inddependent of each other. By adding `global t` you make Python look for t in the module scope instead of in the function scope. Note please, that global variables are considered bad design practice, you can  find out why [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19158339/why-are-global-variables-evil). Besides of that, you have to move the return ***below*** the print, else it wont get executed. `return` immediately returns, all code after it will never be executed.

Answer (score 1):

I just cleaned your code a little bit. Also, I fixed the indentation.

```
import math
c,f = "",""
t = 0

def wind():
    temp_chosen = float(input("What is the temperature? :"))
    scale = input("Farenheit or Celsius (F/C)? ").upper()  
    t = (9/5 * temp_chosen) + 32
    if scale == "C":
        print(t)
    else:
        t = temp_chosen
        for i in range (5, 65, 5):
            wind_chill = 35.74 + (0.6215 * t) -35.75 * (i ** 0.16) + 0.4275 * ((t)) * (i ** 0.16)
            print(f"At temperature {t}F, and wind speed {i} mph, the windchill is: {wind_chill:.2f}F")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    wind()
```